# How do I make Evernote always paste in the matching font?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, evernote

When I paste text from another application into Evernote it always uses some random strange font from the source.

How do I change Evernote so that it keeps the font the same as the font in the note I am pasting the text. It seems fairly logical to me but I cannot fathom why it does anything else!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you want can be achieved using **Paste and Match Style**

- Edit > Paste and Match Style

Keyboard shortcut <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>

[image: Match Style]

This will paste in your clipboard content matching the current style of text in your note.

Comment: It's a pleasure!